# Quartz doesnt end job and/or trigger chained job

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have two quartz jobs, one for Downloading (whose source only is available during specific times) and one for Compressing (to compress the downloaded data), which I have chained with `JobChainingJobListener`.

However, the first Download job never completes (I am spinning on the CancellationToken but it never gets set) - similar to this blog https://blexin.com/en/blog-en/stopping-asynchronous-jobs-of-quartz-3/

I am not sure if Quartz supports external runtime duration, or if I need to manage the runtime within the job (i.e. run for X number of hours and then return). To separate concerns, externally managing this to the job would be best.

In my demo below I have set to run 30 seconds from starting the app and set to end running 30 seconds after it started (but for my real version I run between 9am to 6pm, in the provided timezone).

Greatly appreciate advise as to what i am doing wrong.

```
var scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
var schedule = SchedulerBuilder.Create();
var now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
var startAt = now.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var endAt = startAt.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
Console.WriteLine($"Run from {now} to {endAt}");

var trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .Create()
    .ForJob(downloadJob)
    .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x => x.InTimeZone(timeZoneInfo)
        .StartingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(startAt.Hours, startAt.Minutes, startAt.Seconds))
        .EndingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(endAt.Hours, endAt.Minutes, endAt.Seconds)))
    .Build();

var chain = new JobChainingJobListener("DownloadAndCompress");
chain.AddJobChainLink(downloadJob.Key, compressJob.Key);
scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(chain, GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup());

await this.scheduler.ScheduleJob(downloadJob, trigger, cancellationToken);
await this.scheduler.AddJob(compressJob, true, true, cancellationToken);
await this.scheduler.Start(cancellationToken);
```

And my template jobs are below:

```
class DownloadJob : IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running download job");
        var cancellationToken = context.CancellationToken;

        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End download job");
    }
}

class CompressJob : IJob
{

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running compress job");

        var cancellationToken = context.CancellationToken;

        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End compress job");
    }
}
```